# Map Url field via Object Converter

Tags: community, object, field-mapping, convert

Could you please advise how to make a map between two fields by using the Object Converter.
Here is what I need to achieve
http://postimg.org/image/kzhf2h28p/
Unfortunately the Applicants Website(s) value is not available in the target object field Url (Url__c) dropdown. Could you
please advise how to make it available in the url__c so that I can select it there?

I am using the standard object converter available via Set Up >> Develop >> Custom Settings >> Manage or Set up >> View Installed Packages >> Configure Object Converter

[image: mapping screenshot]

Comment: Can you please include the image in your post instead?

Comment: ok it is included

Comment: You may have to reach out to the package vendor to understand if this is a limitation of their package or a bug.

Comment: Ok but, could you please advise how to reach out the package vendor? I'm not fully aware how to reach the package vendor. Could you please explain?